# splitting list if items more than n elements in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactJS for rendering properly formatted menu on our web app:

How do I stop rendering list and begin from start if number of elements exceeds n(20 in my case)

```
   <div className="dropdown-menu-inner">
{
    item.children ? item.children.map(function (childitem, childindex) {
        return childitem.children ?
            <div id="col_sub_1">
                <ul className="col-lg-3 sub-menu-width">
                    {
                        childitem.id == '39' ?
                            <div class="vl"></div> : <div>{item.name}</div>
                    }
                    <span>{
                        <li className="visible-lg-block">
                            <a ><span>{childitem.name}</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    }

                        {
                            childitem.children.map(function (leaf, leafindex) {
                                return <li className="visible-lg-block">
                                    <a href={leaf.url}><span>{leaf.name}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                            })}</span></ul></div>
            : <li className="visible-lg-block">
                <a href={item.url}><span>{childitem.name}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
    }) : null
}{
    item.images_array ? item.images_array.map(function (image, ind) {
        return <div className="col-sm-6 col-lg-9 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
            <a className="event_menu_item_desktop" href={image.url}>
                <img alt={item.name} className="img-responsive" src={image.src} />
            </a>
        </div>
    }) : null
}
```

What I need to do is limit the number of list items to 20 when iterating leaf elements and have my list rendering from the top if more than 20 elements.

sample data:

```
    {
      "data": {
        "desktop_web_menu": [
    {
            "category_id": 0,
            "children": [
              {
                "category_id": 1000,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "category_id": 604,
                    "id": 5,
                    "image_tag": null,
                    "images_array": [
                      {
                        "src": "/abc/",
                        "url": ""
                      }
                    ],
                    "name": "Back To School",
                    "parent_id": 4,
                    "position": 103,
                    "thumbnail": "abc,jpg",
                    "url": "/abc/"
                  },
                  {
                    "category_id": 607,
                    "id": 6,
                    "image_tag": null,
                    "images_array": [
                      {
                        "src": "zfd",
                        "url": ""
                      }
                    ],
                    "name": "Edgy Edit",
                    "parent_id": 4,
                    "position": 104,
                    "thumbnail": "edit.jpg",
                    "url": "ghvm/"
                  },
                  {
                    "category_id": 697,
                    "id": 7,
                    "image_tag": null,
                    "images_array": [
                      {
                        "src": "vhjk",
                        "url": ""
                      }
                    ],
                    "name": "Colour of the Month: Blue",
                    "parent_id": 4,
                    "position": 105,
                    "thumbnail": "/color.jpg",
                    "url": "/blueyi-collection/"
                  },
                  {
                    "category_id": 725,
                    "id": 8,
                    "image_tag": null,
                    "images_array": null,
                    "name": "Collection",
                    "parent_id": 4,
                    "position": 106,
                    "thumbnail": "/collection.jpg",
                    "url": "collection/"
                  }]}}
```

Comment: what do you mean by leaf elements

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subset of your collection, by using `slice()`:

```
item.children.slice(0, 20).map(function (childitem, childindex) {
...
```

The `slice()` method, returns a new array (your subset), which means you can use `map()` directly on the result.